# Why is the error with this code?

Tags: objective-c

I have:

```
boardValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 2];
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithValuesForKeys: @"sample", @"word", boardValue , @"value", nil];
```

This is very similar to the following example:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

from Apple documentations at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I get the error "too many arguments to method call, expect 1, have 5".  What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` takes [an array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) as an argument, not a variable list of arguments.

(Also, I believe it's an instance method, not a class method, so [NSDictionary dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:args]` won't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Notice your code compared to the documentation.  You want to call...

```
boardValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 2]; 
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"sample", @"word", boardValue , @"value", nil];
```